# Prove that the quantum state fidelity is upper bounded as $F(\rho,\sigma)\le1$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

I am looking for proof that the [quantum fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states) $$F(\rho, \sigma) = \left(\text{tr} \sqrt{\sqrt{\rho}\sigma\sqrt\rho}\right)^2$$ is bound from above by 1, i.e., $F(\rho, \sigma) \leq 1$.

1. I know this is a consequence of [Uhlmann's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states#Uhlmann%27s_theorem). However, I feel like it is far too complicated for this (seemingly) simple task. Is there more straightforward proof of the fact?
2. Also, as far as I know, the inequality is tight only for $\rho = \sigma$. This seems like a more difficult task to prove. Is it still possible in relatively simple manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can equivalently write the (square root of the) fidelity as
$$\sqrt F(\rho,\sigma) = \|\sqrt\rho\sqrt\sigma\|_1,$$
where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the one norm, defined as
$$\|A\|_1=\operatorname{tr}(|A|)=\operatorname{tr}[\sqrt{A^\dagger A}]
= \operatorname{tr}[\sqrt{AA^\dagger}].
$$
A general property of the trace norm $\|A\|_1$ is that it equals the max of $\left|\langle U,A\rangle\right|$ maximised over all unitaries $U$. And in particular, there is always some unitary $U$ such that $\|A\|_1=\langle U,A\rangle\equiv \operatorname{tr}(U^\dagger A)$. It's not crucial to our discussion here, but this $U$ is the unitary arising from the polar decomposition of $A$.

Suppose now $P,Q$ are generic Hermitian matrices. Then for some unitary $U$ we have
$$\|\sqrt P\sqrt Q\|_1 = \langle U, \sqrt P\sqrt Q\rangle
= \langle \sqrt P U,\sqrt Q\rangle,$$
where we are using the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product: $\langle A,B\rangle\equiv \operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger B)$.
Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we get the bound
$$\|\sqrt P\sqrt Q\|_1 \le \|\sqrt P U\|_2 \|\sqrt Q\|_2
= \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt P UU^\dagger \sqrt P)} \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt Q\sqrt Q)},$$
where $\|A\|_2\equiv \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger A)}$.
In conclusion
$$F(P,Q) = \|\sqrt P\sqrt Q\|_1^2 \le \operatorname{tr}(P) \operatorname{tr}(Q),$$
which gives the unit upper bound for normalized density matrices.

Furthermore, the inequality is saturated when the CS inequality is, that is, when $\sqrt P U\propto \sqrt Q$. Being $P,Q$ Hermitian, this holds iff $P$ and $Q$ have the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors. In other words, iff $P=\lambda Q$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. When we are using density matrices, this amounts to $\rho=\sigma$.

You can have a look at [https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI) for (a lot) more details.